# Не работает position: sticky

Tags: html, css

Помогите, я не могу понять, в чем ошибка. position: sticky; не работает. Вот ссылка на сайт, справа есть форма, она должна быть липкой https://olegmukom.ru/sites/kidsFun/provider.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалите строку `overflow-x: hidden;` в классе `.providerpage` (style.css, строка 3324).
Удалите строку `overflow: hidden;` в классе `.row` (style.css, строка 6628).

Comment: Спасибо большое